# SQL Server - How to calculate Stock from In and Out column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table in SQL Server to track Date, Quantity In, & Quantity  Out. I want to calculate current Stock column.

```
Date        InQty      OutQty      Stock
1 Sep 2018  1000        200        800
2 Sep 2018  0           300        500
3 Sep 2018  1000        100        1400
```

I want to create SQL Server Query to calculate the Stock value as shown above. I am really appreciate for any help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(   
    [Date] DATE
   ,[InQty] INT
   ,[OutQty] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Date], [InQty], [OutQty])
VALUES ('20180901', 1000, 200)
      ,('20180902', 0, 300)
      ,('20180903', 1000, 100);

SELECT *
      ,SUM([InQty]-[OutQty]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date])
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY [Date];
```

[image]

Comment: This falls over if there are two transactions on the same date.

Comment: If you have two transactions on the same date you need a way to distinguish them. You can rather use more precision date time type or add another column in the `ORDER BY` clause - record ID, time or something else making your row unique.